# Anaconda environment cannot import module

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pycharm, anaconda

I have installed PyCharm in order to work on Python projects. I have also installed Anaconda to create conda environments for my projects on my machine.

I have create a new project called 'hello-world-ml' and I have created a conda environment called 'hello-world-ml' for my python project.

Within, my python folder I have a script called 'hello-world.py'. Within this script I require the module 'sklearn'. I have activated my conda environment and installed sklearn using the command `conda install scikit-learn`. When I enter `conda list`. I can see that the module has been successfully installed within the conda environment.

I have also configure PyCharm to use the Python interpreter from the conda environment. So when I went to type `from sklearn...` it auto suggested what to import.

When I go to run my script, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello-world.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sklearn import tree
  File "C:\Users\Callu\Anaconda3\envs\hello-world-ml\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 134, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "C:\Users\Callu\Anaconda3\envs\hello-world-ml\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 11, in <module>
    from scipy import sparse
  File "C:\Users\Callu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 118, in <module>
    from scipy._lib._ccallback import LowLevelCallable
  File "C:\Users\Callu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\scipy\_lib\_ccallback.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import _ccallback_c
ImportError: cannot import name '_ccallback_c'
```

I am unsure how to fix this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

In addition, when I deactivate the conda environment and try to run the script it works fine.

Comment: Does `conda list` in your env include also scipy? If not, install it there, too (from the trace you show, it seems it tries to load scipy from a different location/environment)...

Comment: I deleted the conda env and just reinstalled scipy. It now seems to work.